# DataGridView Image Column is throwing an Argument Exception: Parameter not valid

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am trying to load the data from MySQL database where the images are also placed in my table but when the form loads it gives the exception:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

```cs
private void DealSuggestion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        status.Items.Add("active");
        status.Items.Add("inactive");
        id.Visible = false;
        label7.Text = "";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand();
        string query = "SELECT * from dealSuggestion where Status='inactive' LIMIT 8";
        cm.CommandText = query;
        cm.Connection = conn;
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Design View click the Grid, properties/events and DBL click the DataGridView_CellError event to catch the exceptions. Also is there an inner exception?

Comment: i have catch it but the images from data base in not showing in it

Comment: if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

Comment: Please post the exception as text. You can also [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) states that `ArgumentException` is thrown when the stream doesn't have a valid image format or is null. Can you please show us how do you load the image into the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridViewImageColumn dgvimgcol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Check this out
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/insert-images-into-datagridview-in-windows-application-using/

Columns in datagridview are consider as string so you need to create an imagecolumn instead of binding it